# Sort String ArrayList Numerically in Java Android

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` as defined below:

```
List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
where.add("1 Kg");
where.add("500 gram");
where.add("5 Kg");
```

When I display this list, values shown are shown as:

> 1 Kg
>   500 gram
>   5 Kg

I want it to be displayed as given below:

> 500 gram
>   1 Kg
>   5 Kg

How should I sort it.

Comment: You need to work out how to convert everything into a common unit, e.g. grams; and then compare the numerical values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Comparator` where you can write your comparison logic.

See the following implementation.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
        where.add("5 Kg");
        where.add("500 gram");
        where.add("1 Kg");

        Collections.sort(where, new MassComparator());

        for(String mass : where) {
            System.out.println(mass);
        }
    }

    public static class MassComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String weight1, String weight2) {
            double val1 = Double.parseDouble(weight1.replace("gram", "").replace("Kg", "").trim());
            double val2 = Double.parseDouble(weight2.replace("gram", "").replace("Kg", "").trim());

            if (weight1.contains("gram")) {
                val1 *= .001;
            }

            if (weight2.contains("gram")) {
                val2 *= .001;
            }

            int result = 0;

            if (val1 < val2) {
                result = -1;
            } else if (val1 > val2) {
                result = 1;
            }

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

**Input**

```
List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
where.add("500 gram");
where.add("2 Kg");
```

**Output**

```
500 gram
2 Kg
```

Comment: You might want your `result` creation with `return Integer.compare(weight1, weight2);`.

Comment: `weight1` and `weight2` are `String` values. Believe me I didn't like writing this but that was the only way :)

Comment: I meant `val1` and `val2` ;P.

Comment: @Tom ... and Double.compare, probably :P

Comment: @Arjan Yes, indeed ... so my first comment has the right intention, but is full of mistakes ^^.

Comment: @11thdimension It's returning NumberFormatException with error Invalid Double 2 K

Comment: What input are you using ?

Comment: @11thdimension 500 gram and 2 Kg

Comment: It's working fine for these inputs, see my edits in the answer for input and output.

Comment: @11thdimension Ok got it. Done. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to sort `String` representations of values instead of harmonizing the values in your data (e.g. all in grams) and sort them in the natural order of the values only, you'll need quite some work.

1. Use a `Comparator<String>` - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for API. You'll inject this in an invocation of `Collections.sort` when sorting your `List` (API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)).
2. In your `compare` method, parse two things out of each `String` through regular expressions: a number (real or integer, depends on your data) and a measurement unit (possibly based on an map defining all variants for gram, kilogram, etc.)
3. Then compare the measurement units (possibly using another `Comparator<String>`!) and convert the parsed numbers to their values for a single unit (likely grams, etc.)
4. Finally compare the harmonized numerical values after converting them to actual numbers (e.g. `Integer`s or `Double`s, etc.) - using their natural order this time

"Optionally", handle all edge cases: `null` or empty values, `String`s not containing a numerical representation or measurement unit, ambiguous values, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Store your values as Double as shown below

```
List<Double> where = new ArrayList<Double>();
where.add(0.5);
where.add(1);
where.add(5);
```

You can apply sorting on above list, 
also at the time of retrieving you can use 0.5 kg instead of 500 grams if your app requirement allows it.

Answer (score 0):

Mr @11thdimension has already given a perfect working solution. I think you can also use Java 8, if you want. Basically the same idea but less code.

```
List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
    where.add("1 Kg");
    where.add("500 gram");
    where.add("5 Kg");

    Collections.sort(where, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            double a = (Double.parseDouble(o1.replace("gram","").replace("Kg","").trim()))*(o1.contains("gram")?0.001:1);
            double b = (Double.parseDouble(o2.replace("gram","").replace("Kg","").trim()))*(o2.contains("gram")?0.001:1);
            return Double.compare(a,b) ;
        }
    });
    where.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: *"I think you can also use Java 8, if you want."* Well I expected a bit more Java 8, than just a stream to print the sorted List :D. For example using it to actually sort the list.

Comment: @Tom oh yea i think so, you mean with filter and the rest

Comment: Well, `filter` might not be necessary, but yes, stuff like that :D. Or at least `Collections.sort(where, (o1, o2) -> {` instead of `Collections.sort(where, new Comparator<String>() { @Override public int compare(String o1, String o2) {` :D.

Answer (score -1):

just use `index` and `for` cycle,

```
for(int i=0; i<where.size(); i++){
   System.out.println(where.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. Your answer doesn't solve what OPs asks for.

Comment: OP has an amount of Strings with a number and a weight. He wants to sort these list items according to their number and weight (with "kg" being heavier than "gram"). Your code just iterates other the list and ignores the sorting part. And yes, OPs example is misleading.

Comment: @DmitriyPolovinkin  He want to **sort** it: `How should i sort it. ` That it is already sorted - just coincidence.